# Undefined property of object when using define()

Tags: php

Why can I not do something like the following when I know that the property of `myobject` is going to be declared already:

`define('title','boats');`

`myobject->title`;

but this works:

`myobject->boats`

Is this even good practice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use

```
$myobject->title
```

as this is attempting to access the `title` property of your object. If this property does not exist, an error will be triggered.

You can use

```
$myobject->{title}
```

but I'd rather see you use a variable instead of a constant, eg

```
$title = 'boats';
echo $myobject->$title;
```

Ideally, you will know which property you want to access and use its name appropriately

```
$myobject->boats
```

Answer (score 1):

> Why can I not do something like the following when I know that the property of myobject is going to be declared already:

Probably because PHP expects you to call it with a method name. There are options, though:

```
<?php
define( 'METHOD', 'bar' );

class Foo {
    public function bar( ) {
        echo "Foo->bar( ) called.\n";
    }
}

$foo = new Foo;
call_user_func( array( $foo, METHOD ) );

// or
$method = METHOD;
$foo->$method( );
```

**EDIT**: Ah, I seem to have misunderstood. My version is for calling methods of which the name is defined in a constant, whereas you were looking for a way of calling properties. Well, I'll leave it in here for future reference anyway.